# PHP How to foreach explode POST multiple values

Tags: php, post, foreach, explode

I want to foreach explode from POST multiple values

Cut off "1234" with first space (by character not position)

I get error "Array to string conversion"

> Form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="docid[]" value="1234 harry potter">
```

> Submit

```
$docID = $_POST['docid'];
foreach($docID as $val) {
    echo explode(' ', $val);
}
```

> Output

```
1234
```

**EDIT**
I want to insert output to DB

Comment: Try to `print_r($docID)` for see result and post it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Quite simply you cannot echo an array and `explode()` returns an array. BUT you could do `echo explode(' ', $val)[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an *array* of strings, so `echo` won't work. It also has a third parameter, use that to limit the elements returned:

```
<?php 
$docID = $_POST['docid'];
foreach($docID as $val) {
    $exploded = explode(' ', $val, 2);
    // print_r($exploded); # Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => harry potter )
    echo $exploded[0];
}
```

will output `1234`

Edit: if you want to cut off `1234` from your result use `echo $exploded[1];` - this will output `harry potter`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do but based on your code, if you just want to log what you are getting from your explode, simply encapsulate your explode in `print_r()`

e.g:

```
foreach($docID as $val) {
    print_r(explode(' ', $val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```php
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="docid[]" value="1234 harry potter">
    <input type="checkbox" name="docid[]" value="45678 test 123">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php

$docID = $_POST['docid'] ?? [];

foreach ($docID as $val) {
    $values = explode(' ', $val);

    foreach ($values as $v) {
        echo $v . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output (if all checkboxes are checked):

```
1234 harry potter 45678 test 123
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, It work too.

```
$docID = $_POST['docid']

foreach($docID  as $val) {
    echo explode(' ', $val)[0];
    echo '<br>';
}
```